# How to add a div to a webpage via a bookmark?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

So I'm making a video game similar to [Kick Ass](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fkickassapp.com%2F&ei=CWMKVdf8JYH7ggT9koS4Ag&usg=AFQjCNFRbwJT2DMPv88Yy4Qdg-dDmhdztQ&sig2=lsRR3YqYIGgLYqNwqqIulA), which is a game playable on any website. However, This will be an RPG using DOM and JS to move and operate everything. The only trouble is, I need to be able to add the character div to the web page when somebody clicks on the bookmarklet.

Is it possible to add an entirely new div with a set class to the end of a web page using a bookmarklet?

Comment: Hopefully i have covered enough information for you in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first to answer is correct and this should work, i've quickly written an example as well.. Which does something basic with existing styles/classes in this stackoverflow page..

What took the time was finding a style that did not require so many levels of children and also quickly googling what/how a bookmarklet works.. anyway..

```
javascript: (function () { 
    alert('script running, click ok and i should scroll to the bottom');
    var oDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
    var oSpan = document.createElement('span'); 

    oDiv.setAttribute('class','topbar');   
    oDiv.setAttribute('style','color:#fff; text-align:center;');   
    oSpan.innerHTML = "I WAS ADDED USING A EXTERNAL CODE";   

    document.body.appendChild(oDiv); 
    oDiv.appendChild(oSpan); 

    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);

}());
```

The above example is the complete copy and paste example, this i have been testing with chrome on windows.. But requires IE >= 9

**How To Use / Create A Bookmarklet**

1. Copy the above script into your clipboard
2. Create a new bookmark in your browser
3. Name the bookmark anything you want, example "Add Footer"
4. Paste this code into the URL for the bookmark
5. Save the bookmark / changes you have made
6. While on this page, open that bookmark you create... it will execute the code

you should see a black bar with the words "I WAS ADDED USING A EXTERNAL CODE" in white on the bottom of the page, this is for desktop only.. Mobile would be different.

**Notes**

- Using a Anonymous Function is good practice here in my opinion
- Remember that some elements / styles on websites are generated by javascript. So in this case even if you assign the class, it might not always look the same or do anything at all.
- You will see the element with "Inspect Element", but "View Source" will not as this will request a free copy of the webpage without and changes and show you the source.
- If your using a script larger than above, you are best executing it by appending a script tag linking to a file.

**Getting tricky with code / server side** -- *I will base this upon using PHP server side..*

If you want to do more complex things, say for example keep count of how many people have used your bookmarklet or something else that requires storing or accessing information.

You would do something like host the bookmarklet as a javascript file and use an append script tag method to call your script.

This will always keep it lightweight and can be dynamic by using PHP to generate the script.. Simply use a javascript Header in the php file.

You could easily use PHP to count how many times the script has been called / accessed.

Or my personal method would be to use a form of ajax to send and receive data / requests to your PHP server. This would mean using basic GET/POST type requests.

In the end, you could have a bookmarklet that loads in a custom menu, locates the best position and style to display it's self based upon the website and would show a live stream of data with various controls for the website.

That should cover a few things, Various Source: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-bookmarklets-the-right-way--net-18154

**EDIT - Canvas Example For You**

```
javascript: (function () { 
    alert('script running, click ok and i should scroll to the bottom');
    var oDiv = document.createElement('div');   
    oDiv.setAttribute('class','character');   
    oDiv.setAttribute('style','color:#fff; text-align:center;');      

    var oCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');   
    oCanvas.setAttribute('class','gameCanvas');   
    oCanvas.setAttribute('style','width: 100%; height:100%; z-index:999999; position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; background-color:#d00;');   

    document.body.appendChild(oDiv);    
    document.body.appendChild(oCanvas);   

}());
```

With this example, i've made a few changes from your scribblehub js.. Mainly the styling applied to the canvas, it was being added.. But was not visible as such... So this example should show a red one full size always on top.. increased z-index and added background color.. Used position absolute as this will move it to top left... not the bottom of the page.

Also renamed the variables as having a js variable named canvas is a bad idea

Comment: I am also wanting to use this method to add a <canvas> element to overlay the entire webpage. Would using `var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');` to make the canvas, and using `document.html.appendChild(canvas);` make a canvas element that spans the entire webpage?

Comment: This would add a canvas yes, But you would need to still apply some styling to it. Appending a element such as a div/canvas will create it with its default style.

Comment: I made this. This should add an invisible canvas to overlay the entire webpage, shouldnt it? http://www.scribblehub.com/WebJourney/setup.js

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use code like the following:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'some-class';
// set other properties here
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: Would the div show up in inspect element and/or view source? I attached the following to a bookmark, and when clicking it, nothing happens(Like it should) but I dont see the div anywhere in the code.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               `javascript:var%20div%20=%20document.createElement('div');%20div.className%20=%20'character';document.body.appendChild(div);void();`

Comment: Try using [this page](http://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/) to convert your code to a bookmarklet. You can also minify it first before doing so. The link that it creates when copying in my code works fine for me.